# Slow file writing on Linux embedded system

Tags: linux, file, file-io, embedded

I have multiple writes on a same database file. We insert and update many entries in the DB file. I have seen that insert and update in the file takes some (X) milliseconds to complete the task. Once in a while after 1500 inserts/updates time taken to insert and update is 20X. Again it starts inserting/updating normally. Can I know whats the reason for this. My page size is 512 Bytes. I use paged writing into the DB file.

Comment: Hi @Bharadwaj, what storage type was the DB file written to? May you please check the storage speed first and then investigate your SW implementation

Comment: Could you tell us your hardware specs (core and bus frequency) as well as show some of the code you wrote for writing data?